# Executar função sempre que modificar, criar, excluir post

Tags: wordpress

Galera boa noite, preciso executar uma função no wordpress sempre que um post for incluido, excluido, editado e voltado da lixeira. Alguém pode me ajudar não sei como fazer isso.

Obrigado.

Comment: Poste o código que você já fez.

Comment: comece pesquisando por aqui: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action

Comment: @RicardoHenrique acho que ele não conseguiu construir nenhum código, ele diz no post que não sabe como fazer isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está procurando por [actions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference). Com eles, você pode atrelar métodos que você define a certos "eventos" que ocorrem no WP. Por exemplo, se você colocar, no seu `functions.php` o código

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'init_admin_custom_css' );
function init_admin_custom_css(){
    add_editor_style( get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/meu_css.css' );
}
```

o WP vai inserir este `.css` na tela do editor, toda vez que você entrar no menu de administração (i.e., a action `admin_init`). No seu caso, para realizar uma ação toda vez que um post é editado, por exemplo, você pode fazer

```
add_action('edit_post', 'minha_funcao');
```

e definir

```
function minha_funcao(){
    .
    . #seu código
    .
}
```

Veja [aqui](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) uma lista com os `action`s que o WP disponibiliza, e escolha-os de acordo com a sua necessidade. [Nesta parte](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_insert_post) do codex, você pode observar o `wp_insert_post`, que vai fazer parte do seu código. Leia mais sobre o método `add_action`, suas peculiaridades e seus parâmetros [aqui](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action).

P.S. Todos os 4 links são do codex, o qual recomendo fortemente a leitura.